# Checking when a TabBar item is clicked - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `ViewController` with 2 `sub containers`.  The first `sub container` points to a `ViewController` with a `TabBar` inside it.  The second `sub container` is a `ViewController` that contains a `collection view`.  Now my issue is trying to access the first `sub containers` `TabBar` so that when an Item is clicked, I can know which item is clicked and process my data.

The main `ViewController` has a class.  All the other `sub containers` for that `ViewController` also have a class.  Here is the `.h` for my `sub container` with the `Tab Bar`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface home_tab : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>{

}
@end
```

`.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"working");

}
```

Now when clicking on the `Tab Bar` that is populated, `didSelectViewController` is never called.

I am using storyboard.

Suggestions and thoughts?

Comment: How about using a Singleton to keep track of which view is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple problems atleast from what I can see here,

1. You are using a `TabBar` inside of a `ViewController`, not a `UITabBarController`, thus you need to use `UITabBarDelegate` not `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. You will have to manage the view controllers or whatever view you will want to be loaded on your own most likely with the delegate callback:

   `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;`

Also you dont have a `UITabBar` defined in your controller, therefore your `ViewController` has no idea you have a `UITabBar` in your Storyboard. You need something like this:

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;

    @end
```

Then you will need to Control drag from the `ViewController` to your `UITabBar` and back to connect the Delegate in your Storyboard.

Id recommend using a `UITabBarController` so you dont have to manage the views yourself depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self tabBarController]setDelegate:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

It's just an suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

`[[self tabBarController]selectedIndex]`  This will return the index of the selected tab.

Answer (score 1):

the didSelectViewController method is part of the UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol and is called on the UITabBarController's delegate. Did you set the delegate of the tab bar controller to the current instance of your subcontainer? Inside ViewDidLoad: do something like this:

```
[self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
```

You can also set a delegate on the UITabBar rather than the controller, and the UITabBarDelegate Protocol contains a method tabBar:didSelectItem: that would be called.

Comment: Rob, no I don't think I have.  Could you provide me with an example of pointing it to this current class?

Comment: yup, added the relevant line! If that is not working you should set a breakpoint and make sure that self.tabBarController is not null at the time this executes. If necessary you can move it to a segue method or somewhere later.

Comment: It looks like maybe the tab bar is actually part of a different view controller that the subcontainer has a reference to, not part of the subcontainer itself? If so you need `[otherVC.tabBarController setDelegate:self]`, assuming the other VC already exists at this point.

Comment: Can we have more information like VC you have ? The TabBarController has been added with the Storyboard into home_tab ?

Comment: @thedjnivel I only have a `ViewController` with a `Tab Bar` in it i don't have a `TabBarController`

Comment: In that case, try my suggestion at end "You can also set a delegate on the UITabBar rather than the controller, and the UITabBarDelegate Protocol contains a method tabBar:didSelectItem: that would be called."